# Getting COleDateTime::Format to return "stycznia" instead of "styczeń" for Polish month "January"

Tags: mfc, locale, polish, coledatetime

I have this method to set the locale to Polish:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::SetLocale()
{
    // https://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx#ISO2
    CString strLang[NUM_LANGUAGES] =
    {
        _T("plk")
        // Add more languages here
    };

    _tsetlocale(LC_ALL, strLang[m_eLanguage - LANGUAGE_ENGLISH]);
}
```

I have cut the other languages out for brevity. Now, when I format a `COleDateTime` object and display the month, say January, it shows as:

> styczeń

But i want to show it as:

> stycznia

Is there a locale setting to adjust the month values returned by the `COleDateTime::Format` method or locale?

Otherwise I will have to add something manual to override.

The months I would like returned are:

1. stycznia
2. lutego
3. marca
4. kwietnia
5. maja
6. czerwca
7. lipca
8. sierpnia
9. września
10. października
11. listopada
12. grudnia

## Update

According to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194815.aspx) it states:

> Some languages, such as Finnish, German, **Polish**, and Russian, have
>   several noun forms. If you plan to use localized names provided by the
>   system, have a linguist check to make sure you are using them in the
>   right context. Windows carries both the nominative and genitive forms
>   of **Polish** and Russian month names; **the form changes depending on
>   the month name's position in the string relative to the day name**.
>   Windows returns both forms in a single string separated by a null
>   value. **The system carries only one form of each month name or day
>   name for all other languages**.

Now, this is how I am actually formatting my date strings (since I am supporting over 40 languages it is a bit tricky. So, (for English) I start with this format string:

```
%1 %2!d!-%3!d!
```

1. `%1` is the **month**.
2. `%2!d!` is the **first day** value.
3. `%3!d!` is the **second day** value.

If my date needs to cater for crossing over two months, I have:

```
%1 %2!d!–%3 %4!d!
```

1. `%1` is the **month** value.
2. `%2!d!` is the **first day** value.
3. `%3` is the **second month** value.
4. `%3!d!` is the **second day** value.

The above is used like this:

```
if (datThisMonday.GetMonth() == datEndOfWeek.GetMonth())
{
    strDate.FormatMessage(IDS_STR_TPL_OCLM_WEEK,
            datThisMonday.Format(_T("%B")), datThisMonday.GetDay(), datEndOfWeek.GetDay());
}
else
{
    strDate.FormatMessage(IDS_STR_TPL_OCLM_WEEK2,
            datThisMonday.Format(_T("%B")), datThisMonday.GetDay(),
            datEndOfWeek.Format(_T("%B")), datEndOfWeek.GetDay());
}
```

For *Polish*, my respective format strings are:

```
%2!d!-%3!d! %1
%2!d! %1–%4!d! %3
```

So, I can see that because I am formatting the the date string using `FormatMessage` and only using the `COleDateTime::Format` method to parse just the **month** that it is potentially the cause of the issue.

Since I have two dates in the date string I can't just use a single Date formatting API call (since my date string is representing a week span).

So I checked:

```
strDate = datThisMonday.Format(_T("%d %B"));
```

And it made no difference. So I tried this instead:

```
SYSTEMTIME sTime;
datThisMonday.GetAsSystemTime(sTime);
GetDateFormat(GetThreadLocale(), 
              DATE_LONGDATE, 
              &sTime, _T("d MMMM"), 
              strDate.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), _MAX_PATH);
```

It made no difference. It still shows the date the same way as before. Even if it did display the date correctly it doesn't factor for a **date range** from two COleDateTime objects.

Confused.

## Update 2:

Also tried:

```
TCHAR szDate[100] = _T("");
GetDateFormatEx(_T("pl"), NULL, &sTime, _T("ddd MMMM"), szDate, 100, NULL);
AfxMessageBox(szDate);
```

Just will not show the variant.

## Update 3

The only way I can get it to show the right date is like this:

```
GetDateFormatEx(_T("pl"), DATE_LONGDATE, &sTime, NULL, szDate, 100, NULL);
```

Then the month is correct. Now in the article I referred to it states:

> Windows returns both forms in a single string separated by a null
>   value.

I can't even work out how to access that.

Comment: Google result for "translate january to polish" gives me `"styczeń"`, Windows seems to have it right. Is it supposed to be `"stycznia"`?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I am not an expert, but it can be either. Try translating in reverse, using the second way. Look here: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~dan/genealogy/Miller/resource/polmonth.htm. The alternative way is what is being used in a resource that I am trying to replicate.

Comment: I think "styczeń" is the correct one. I think this is from Windows resources in `GetLocaleInfo` (these settings can be changed but it will affect all applications, not recommended). I would just take the input and replace the wrong month names with the right month names.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated. when You enumerate months "styczeń" is the correct value. but when You specify the date, like 15.01.2019, correct is "15 stycznia 2019 " it's a bit similar like in English You would say 15 - fifteen, but the date would be 15-th fifteenth. 
I will search a bit in polish resources, when I find answer I will answer.

Comment: @CADDeveloper See updated question.

Comment: "Styczeń" and "Stycznia" can both be used, in Polish when you say it in your head it makes sense. Stycznia would be 100% grammatically correct but even if Styczeń was used no one would really notice the difference since its a minuscule detail which when reading out still makes sense
In other words
"stycznia" is valid a "styczneń" is correct
I tried to find someting, but need to spend more time than I have today.

Comment: @CADDeveloper OK, since a user has picked up on this I have decided to add my own text file and replace the date specifiers manually. I take your point that this is a minor matter. Thank you.

Comment: @CADDeveloper I found an article https://rluzynski.fedorapeople.org/slides/2017-01-27-DevConf.cz/GenitiveMonths-updated.pdf and I will provide my answer later today. I have it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered other issues but they are distinct from this question, so I will still provide my answer here.

Firstly, I found a [document](https://rluzynski.fedorapeople.org/slides/2017-01-27-DevConf.cz/GenitiveMonths-updated.pdf) which states that you must have `d` in the date for it to show the correct version of the month.

Since, I am wanting to display a date range, I start with this:

## Polish

Template: `%1-%2`
Date 1: `d`
Date 2: `d MMMM`

Then I format the date:

```
SYSTEMTIME sysTime;
ENSURE(rDate.GetAsSystemTime(sysTime));
GetDateFormatEx(_T("pl"),
    NULL,
    &sysTime, 
    strDateFormat, 
    strDate.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), _MAX_PATH, nullptr);
```

That displays it correctly. And if the date range spans two months I have:

Template: `%1-%2`
Date 1: `d MMMM`
Date 2: `d MMMM`

It works well.

Answer (score 1):

Since Windows 7, you can also use the `LOCALE_RETURN_GENITIVE_NAMES` to return the genitive name of a month. Running this :

```
const wchar_t localeName[] = L"pl-PL";
for (LCTYPE m = LOCALE_SMONTHNAME1; m <= LOCALE_SMONTHNAME12; ++m) {
  wchar_t buf[1024];
  GetLocaleInfoEx(localeName, m | LOCALE_RETURN_GENITIVE_NAMES, buf, sizeof(buf) / sizeof(*buf));
  std::cout << to_utf8(buf) << '\n';
}
```

Gives the following result :

```
stycznia
lutego
marca
kwietnia
maja
czerwca
lipca
sierpnia
września
października
listopada
grudnia
```

which are indeed proper genitive names for months in Polish.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Although, I am trying to format an actual date / date range and not obtain a specific month name. So my code has to cater for both types of month names.